# What causes R's "seasonal" package/function to not return an adjusted series?

Tags: r

I'm trying to get a seasonally adjusted version of two similar-looking series. The `seas` function works for the first and seems to silently fail to return data for the second. What's going on with this second series?

```
library(seasonal)

ts1 = structure(c(151, 162, 244, 184, 226, 244, 196, 199, 196, 150, 
158, 90, 163, 157, 226, 243, 251, 260, 211, 261, 190, 189, 154, 
111, 255, 166, 223, 231, 306, 303, 268, 256, 189, 202, 145, 105, 
222, 201, 232, 177, 239, 256, 285, 222, 216, 219, 190, 162, 232, 
180, 256, 293, 280, 283, 239, 248, 242, 205, 164, 136, 153, 136, 
182, 217), .Tsp = c(2017, 2022.25, 12), class = "ts")
ts2 = structure(c(102, 125, 166, 151, 203, 183, 174, 174, 166, 155, 
152, 124, 108, 108, 129, 175, 243, 206, 181, 210, 135, 152, 152, 
132, 98, 113, 182, 184, 228, 179, 190, 190, 157, 157, 133, 141, 
127, 183, 176, 156, 100, 207, 255, 230, 202, 213, 169, 180, 153, 
145, 186, 221, 238, 286, 227, 213, 229, 193, 211, 214, 158, 163, 
143, 184), .Tsp = c(2017, 2022.25, 12), class = "ts")

ts1
ts2

final(seas(ts1))
final(seas(ts2))
```

Comment: I ran your code as it is. Where does final() come from? I get an error

Comment: @OTA The `seasonal` package. I edited the question to include the correct package name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a rather short time series and x-13 tries to detect and estimate outliers, a trading day effect, whilst also finding an optimal ARIMA model and testing whether Easter has an impact. Depending on you prior knowledge about the series, you may decide to go any of the following routes:

1. Leave out (parts of) outlier adjustment.

Keep in mind, that the X-11 seasonal adjustment part of X-13 includes an extreme value detection, which may be sufficient to handle very irregular observations.

```
    final(seas(ts2, outlier=NULL))
```

2. Set the arima model to be used

E.g. the Airline model - SARIMA(0,1,1)(0,1,1), which often is a good starting point for seasonal series.

```
    final(seas(ts2, arima.model = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1)))
```

3. Exclude trading day estimation

If trading day effects are not to be expected, then you may want to exclude them from the esimation

```
    final(seas(ts2, regression.aictest=NULL))
```